# Create a dynamic iframe that receive its URL from the address bar

Tags: html, iframe, google-sites

I have a simple website, and I'd like to hide some URL addresses using iframe.

Is there any way to create a code that receive the ifram's URL from the address?
Something like that:
www.myschool.com/**iframe?url=www.stackoverflow.com**

I'm looking for a code that enables to automatically receive the iframe's URL (www.stackoverflow.com) from the address bar, to be embedded in my website.

Thanks!

Comment: That looks like a simple PHP task, but you should be aware that using CSP, not all pages allow to be displayed in an iFrame.

Comment: If an address bar has a url of the page it is on: `http://example.com/` and you have an iframe with `src="http://example.com`... isn't that just a window into where you already are? It makes very little sense.

Comment: Absolutely not. The idea is to have a dynamic iframe in your webpage, that gets its url from the address bar. For example: http://example.com/iframe?url=www.stackoverflow.com. In that way, Stackoverflow will be embedded into example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the split method on the string of the url and take everything after the '?' by targetting the [1] position of the resulting array, then change the iframe's 'src' attribute to that url.

<del>var url = window.location.href.split('?')[1];

    document.querySelector('iframe').setAttribute('src',url);</del>

Try breaking the first line into two like this:

```
var url = window.location.href;
url.split('?')[1];
document.querySelector('iframe').setAttribute('src',url);
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your response! I tried to use your method but it didn’t work out... it targeted the [1] position but couldn’t apply this in the iframe..

Comment: hmmm... try breaking up the first line into:

var url = window.location.href;
url.split('?')[1];
document.querySelector('iframe').setAttribute('src',url);

also get rid of that "<br>". No idea why I had that in there lol

Comment: I fixed it above, ignore that mess of code; I just learned that formatting isn't maintained in comments :/